# JS Module pattern and invoking another function

Tags: javascript, oop

So I have repeatedly run into this situation: I write a module patterned object, but am unable to invoke one function from within another (prototyped) function.

```
;(function($,window,documnet,undefined) {
    var id,
        _defaults = { };

    var MyObject = function(element,options) {
        this.el = element;
        this.opt = $.extend({},_defaults,options);
        this.init();   //  works fine
    };

    MyObject.prototype.init = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.id = localStorage.getItem('myobject_id');
        if( self.id !== null ) {
             $('#myobject_id').val(self.id);
        }
    };


    MyObject.prototype.fetch = function() {
        var self = this;
        var data = { 
                    action: 'program_fetch',
                    program_idx: $('#program_idx').val()
                   };

        // assume session is valid and has a uri in opt.callback
        $.post( session.opt.callback, data ).complete(function(r){
            var prog = JSON.parse(r.responseText).program;
            self.id = prog.id;

            $('#myobject_id').val( self.id );  // this works

            self.display();                    // this does not work
        });

    }; /* fetch */


    MyObject.prototype.display = function() {
        var self = this;

        $('#myobject_id').val( self.id );

    };  /* display */


    $.fn.MyObject = function(options) {
        return this.each(function(){
            if(!$.data(this,'plugin_MyObject')) {
                $.data(this,'plugin_MyObject', new MyObject(options));
            }
        });
    };

    window.myobject = new MyObject();

})(jQuery,window,document);
```

From what I understand, the fetch function *ought to be* setting the value of the window-attached instance of MyObject, so that when the display() function is called, it has a value to place into the HTML input field, identified by #myobject_id.

What actually seems to happen is there is a race condition during which the value assigned to self.id is viable, but leaving the scope of the .complete(..) callback the value of MyObject.id is no longer valid.

How ought I be invoking these things to achieve persistence in the instance data within my object ?

Comment: That should work. Are you sure the problem isn't the bad selector in `MyObject.prototype.display` ('$myobject_id' instead of '#myobject_id')?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need the `window.myobject = new MyObject();` line if you're only ever instantiating `MyObject`'s through the jQuery plugin pattern.

Comment: See my "Answer" below. It turns out in part at least I was masking the properties of MyObject by using var self = this; within the each function scope.

Comment: I can't see your answer or where you're doing the `var self = this;` insode of an `each`...

Comment: MyObject.prototype.fetch = function() {
        var self = this;

Comment: Nevermind, your answer just showed up.  You should setup a jsfiddle or something - I think you're perhaps barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Are you sure `.display()` isn't being invoked?  Try putting a `console.log()` or an `alert()` in there.  And even in your modified version below, you still have a bogus selector (the `$` should be a `#`).  The `self` reference *should* work in your original one, but will definitely be broken in your modified version because `self` will now be undefined when you try to call `self.display()`.

Comment: You also seem to have some confusion in how you're using `id`.  Sometimes you're referencing `self.id` and other times you're referencing an `id` in your top-level closure.  Based on how you're using it, I'd assume you want to stick with `self.id` so it's unique per instance of `MyObject`.

Answer (score 1):

```
;(function($,window,documnet,undefined) {
var id, 
    _defaults = { };

var MyObject = function(element,options) {
    this.el = element;
    this.opt = $.extend({},_defaults,options);
    this.init();   //  works fine
};

MyObject.prototype.init = function() {

    id = localStorage.getItem('myobject_id');
    if( id !== null ) {
         $('#myobject_id').val(id);
    }
};

    MyObject.prototype.fetch = function() {
    var data = { 
                action: 'program_fetch',
                program_idx: $('#program_idx').val()
               };

    // assume session is valid and has a uri in opt.callback
    $.post( session.opt.callback, data ).complete(function(r){
        var prog = JSON.parse(r.responseText).program;
        id = prog.id;

        $('#myobject_id').val( id );  // this works
        self.display();               // this does not work
    });

}; /* fetch */


MyObject.prototype.display = function() {
    $('#myobject_id').val( id );
};  /* display */


$.fn.MyObject = function(options) {
    return this.each(function(){
        if(!$.data(this,'plugin_MyObject')) {
            $.data(this,'plugin_MyObject', new MyObject(options));
        }
    });
};

})(jQuery,window,document);
```

In this version I have removed the pattern of using var self = this;  within each function scope, as it was masking the object level variables of the same names. (Can't set object properties through this.var?)

There is still the outstanding issue of **self.display()** not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

The simple truth is I didn't know how to structure a class object in JS. Here's a simple model:

```
;(function($,window) {

    var self;
    var MyClass = function(opt) {
        self = this;
        return self.init(opt);
    }

    MyClass.prototype = {

        init: function(opt) {
            self.opt = $.extend({},opt);
            // other set up stuff
            return self;
        },

        display: function() {

        },

        show: function() {
            self.display();
        }
    }; /* end of prototype */

    $.fn.myclass = function(opt) {
        return new MyClass(opt);
    }

}(jQuery,window));  /* end of clas object */

jQuery().ready(function($) {
    window.myInstance = $().myclass({ /* options here */ });
    $('#some_button').click( window.myInstance.show );
}
```

On activation of the button `#some_button` the show method is invoked. It in turn will invoke the display() method.  Easy peasy.